# Error en la acumulación de un valor JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type="button" onclick="obtener()" value="SACAR GANADOR">
<script>
var contador1 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;
  function obtener() {
var b = Math.random() * 10;


if (b > 5) {
  
  contador1 += ++contador1;
  
  
}
else if(b <= 5) {
  
  contador2 += ++contador2;
  
}

if (contador1 == 3) {
  
  console.log('el ganador es el jugador 1');
    
}

else if (contador2 == 3) {
  console.log('El ganador es el jugador 2');

}
else {
  console.log(contador1);
  console.log(contador2);
  
  
}
}
</script>
```

***Por qué la consola muestra numeros que no esperaba, todo el tiempo ? Se supone que según el numero se le sumará 1 , pero porqué no es así?***

Comment: Cada que mandas llamar tu función reinicializas tus variables `contador` y nunca lograrán llegar al valor que esperas, además `contado1 += contador1++` es igual a esto `0 + (0 + 0)`

Comment: edité el código y he definido las variables fuera de la función, pero aún asi no funciona

Comment: Es por lo segundo, `contador1 += contador1++` es igual a esto `0 + (0+0)` Puedes dejar tus variables = 1 y solo hacer `contador++`

Comment: lo he cambiado por ++contador y me da numeros cada vez más gigantes , que pasa?

Comment: Edita mejor tu pregunta amigo.

Comment: cual es el problema gilberto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es la siguiente línea `contador1 += ++contador1;`, ya que incrementa el valor en 1 y luego se suma a sí mismo, algo así

*Primera iteración*
contador1 = ( 1 + 0 ) + 0

*Segunda iteración*
contador1 = ( 1 + 1 ) + 1

*Tercera iteración*
contador1 = (1 + 3 ) + 3

*Cuarta iteración*
contador1 = (1 + 7) + 7

y así sucesivamente

para sumar solo una unidad puedes hacer lo siguiente
`contador1 += 1;` O `contador1++;` O `++contador1;`

y aqui está como funcionaría

```js
var contador1 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;
  function obtener() {
var b = Math.random() * 10;


if (b > 5) {
  contador1++;
}else if(b <= 5) { 
  contador2++;
}

if (contador1 == 3) {
  console.log('el ganador es el jugador 1');   
}else if (contador2 == 3) {
  console.log('El ganador es el jugador 2');
}else {
  console.log(contador1);
  console.log(contador2); 
}
}
```

```html
votar en contra
favorito

<input type="button" onclick="obtener()" value="SACAR GANADOR">
```